# How to obtain substring of big string text in Python?

Tags: python, api, file, text

I have the following format of text files, which are outputs of an API:

```
TASK [Do this]
OK: {
    "changed":false,
    "msg": "check ok"
}

TASK [Do that]
OK

TASK [Do x]
Fatal: "Error message x"

TASK [Do y]
OK

TASK [Do z]
Fatal: "Stopped because of previous error"
```

The amount of lines, or tasks before and after the "Fatal" error are random,  and I am only interested in the "Error message x" part.

Code as of now:

```
url = # API URL 
r = request.get(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers, timeout=10)
output = r.text
```

I tried using a combination of `output.split("Fatal", 1)[1]` but it seems to return `list index out of range`, while also messing up the text, adding a lot of `\n`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a block of text you can split on `\n\n` into chunks of `TASK...\n[Result]` -- and then split each of those chunks on `\n`, looking for a line that starts with `Fatal`, yeah?

Comment: If you got an IndexError that means that the string didn't contain `"Fatal"`. You can wrap the `split` in `try`/`except`, or use `output.split("Fatal", 1)[-1]` to avoid an error when there is no split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` package to use a regular expression to search for the text you need. There are probably more optimal regex, but I wrote this one quickly using regex101.com: `Fatal: "(.+)"`

```
import re

s = '''TASK [Do this]
OK: {
    "changed":false,
    "msg": "check ok"
}

TASK [Do that]
OK

TASK [Do x]
Fatal: "Error message x"

TASK [Do y]
OK

TASK [Do z]
Fatal: "Stopped because of previous error"'''

errors = re.findall(r'Fatal: "(.+)"', s)

for x in errors:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular expressions with the re package to do that fairly easily. If it is possible for more than one occurrence of "Error Message X" then using something along the lines of

```
someVar = re.findall("Error Message X", output)
```

should return a list of all occurrences of strings within the output text that match. Findall can also be used if only one occurrence is possible, it will then just return a list with only one element.

Here is a helpful site for an intro to re
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: The thing is that I do not know the exact content of the error message and the error messages vary a lot, but I want to obtain them.

Comment: In that case you should be able to use regular expressions still, it will just be a bit different. If there is a certain character or string that you know will always appear at the end of the message (hypothetically ^) then you can do something like re.findall(r'Error Message(.*?)^', output)